# CSS Accordion - Need to replace a div with a class

Tags: css, accordion

In the original accordion I ended up using:

```
.accordion div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:311px;
}
```

So that any div located inside the accordion followed those specifics.
When I had to find/remake a new accordion (Damn you IE8!) The new accordion contains a div in it already.

Would it be possible to create a new class to replace the div? So it would be like

```
.accordion **uniqueclass?**{
        display:inline-block;
        width:311px;
    }
```

That way it wont interfere with the div that's already there. I wasn't sure if you could specify a class after already specifying one.

As always, I'm a CSS noob so explain in English please :D

Comment: yes you can : for example : `.accordian .round{border-radius:250px;}` this will give every element in .accordian with the class .round a border-radius

Comment: not sure where this other div is but if you are only trying to style direct child divs of the accordion you could try `.accordion > div {}`. If you add the html of the accordions we can give a better answer

Comment: Thanks DiederikEEn, just added a unique class and it's fixed the problem I was having.

Comment: Could you pick an answer?

Answer (score 0):

".according div" selects all the divs within ".accordion". You could replace "div" with any other class and assign it to the divs within accordion, and it should work.

Example:

```
.accordion div.anything {
}
```

would select div with .accordion, but not other divs.

```
<section class="accordion">
<div></div>
<div class="anything"></div>
<div></div>
</section>
```

This should help you understand CSS selectors: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: This should work. Also it would work if you would make a child of the parent. Something like this: .accordion > div{} . This works for sure aswell!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can : for example : .accordian .round{border-radius:250px;} this will give every element in .accordian with the class .round a border-radius – DiederikEEn

- Just wanted to have this as an answer, since it was the simplest solution to the question. Thanks again DiederikEEn.